# Fullwidth section heading in twosided layout

Tags: spacing

I've been trying to achieve a full width chapter/section heading in a twosided layout for a while now. In a previous question: [Spurious white space from a page number conditional](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244396/spurious-white-space-from-a-page-number-conditional) I have inquired about an issue with white space, which is somehow only triggered inside a redefinition of `\section` (I could not reproduce it otherwise). An (updated) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[paperwidth=483pt, paperheight=682pt, left=40pt, top=40pt, textwidth=283pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=51\baselineskip, footskip=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\titleformat{name=\section}%
{}%
{}%
{0pt}%
{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}
  \vrule height .8\textheight width \linewidth
  \end{adjustwidth*}%
  \clearpage%
  }%
\begin{document}
\section{x}
stuff
\clearpage
stuff
\end{document}
```

shows that the text on the first page after `\section` has spurious vertical space which I can't account for. (Note that you can fill in any value for the `\vrule` height, or the arguments of `adjustwidth`, in all cases the spurious white space occurs.)

I've also contemplated the answer provided by egreg, also for larger boxes, which he recommended `adjustbox` for. The same issue occurs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=483pt, paperheight=682pt, left=40pt, top=40pt, textwidth=283pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=51\baselineskip, footskip=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\titleformat{name=\section}%
{}%
{}%
{0pt}%
{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \begin{adjustbox}{height={\textheight},width={\dimexpr\linewidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}}
  \vrule height .4\textheight width \linewidth
  \end{adjustbox}%
  \clearpage%
  }%
\begin{document}
\section{x}
stuff
\clearpage
stuff
\end{document}
```

I'd like to explicitly reevaluate why this is happening and explore alternatives if there is no possible way to fix my (admittedly rather clumsy) construction of `\section` using `adjustwidth`.

Comment: try `{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}
  \vrule height .8\textheight width \linewidth
  \end{adjustwidth*}%
  \clearpage%
  }[\vspace{-1cm}]%`

Comment: @touhami Yes, I have considered it, though that's just papering over the cracks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `\clearpage` to the last optional argument for `\titleformat` (this last optional argument is for material after the title body, so it's appropriate for a `\clearpage`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[paperwidth=483pt, paperheight=682pt, left=40pt, top=40pt, textwidth=283pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=51\baselineskip, footskip=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\titleformat{name=\section}%
{}%
{}%
{0pt}%
{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}
  \vrule height .8\textheight width \linewidth
  \end{adjustwidth*}%
  }[\clearpage]%
\begin{document}

\section{x}
stuff
\clearpage
stuff
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]