# Spurious white space when adding vertical space to start of the page, in redefinition of \section

Tags: spacing

As a followup question to [Fullwidth section heading in twosided layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260459/fullwidth-section-heading-in-twosided-layout) I'd also like to inquire about vertical spacing on new pages. The idea is that the top element of the section title starts somewhere in the middle of the page, and the text block on the next page starts equally as low. The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[paperwidth=483pt, paperheight=682pt, left=40pt, top=40pt, textwidth=283pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=51\baselineskip, footskip=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\newdimen\mydimen
\mydimen=0pt
\titleformat{name=\section}%
{}%
{}%
{0pt}%
{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vspace*{\mydimen}
  \begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}%
  %
  \begin{minipage}[t][.8\textheight]{\linewidth}
  x
  \end{minipage}
  \end{adjustwidth*}%
  }[\clearpage
  \vspace*{\mydimen}
  ]%
\begin{document}
\section{x}
x
\clearpage
\noindent x
\end{document}
```

should intuitively have the result that all three x's at the top of the page are vertically as well as horizontally aligned. This doesn't seem to be the case (somehow). How can I align all three x's here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `adjustwidth`: just define a wide enough minipage and put it in a zero width box.

Next, set the spacings for `\section` to zero except the last that must be `-\baselineskip`.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newlength\mydimen

\titleformat{name=\section}
  {}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
   \thispagestyle{empty}%
   \vspace*{\mydimen}%
   \makebox[0pt][l]{%
     \begin{minipage}[t][.8\textheight]{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}
     x
     \end{minipage}%
   }
  }
  [\clearpage\vspace*{\mydimen}]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\section{x}
x
\clearpage
\noindent x
\end{document}
```

I can't see what's the role of `\mydimen`.

Comment: This is a nice answer. I'm accepting it. Note for passers-by: I've replaced `\vspace*` with `\vskip\mydimen` and set the third argument to `\titlespacing` to be `0pt` as well. I'm not sure why it works, but it does. And that's fine by me. :-)